# teradata : calculating diffreence between 2 timeintervals

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I want to calculate the time difference between 2 time intervals like as shown in the code

```
replace procedure database.table()               
begin  
declare v_StartTime Timestamp;  
decalre v_EndTime Timestamp;        
decalre v_TimeTaken Varchar(20);         

set v_StartTime = current_timestamp;       
/* set of queries...........          
...................                
.....................             

*/       
set v_EndTime =current_timestamp;

set v_timeTaken = v_EndTime - v_StartTime ;

/* I want the time difference in secs or mins*/

End;
```

Is there any other better way to get the time intervals in mins or secs

Answer (score 1):

This should get your elapsed time in seconds.

```
set v_TimeTaken = 
   (EXTRACT(DAY    FROM (v_EndTime - v_StartTime DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 86400)
 + (EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM (v_EndTime - v_StartTime DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 3600)
 + (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (v_EndTime - v_StartTime DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 60)
 +  EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (v_EndTime - v_StartTime DAY(4) TO SECOND))
```

Timestamp arithmetic in Teradata is always something I have to look up. It's not something I do regularly and it's not intuitive like, say, Oracle's method.